# Material design conventions: toolbar text content

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

**Preface**: while this may seem like a question based on personal preference, I am fairly sure there are set guidelines for material layouts, providing rules to adhere to. (I just cant seem to find them)

In order to prepare for an upcoming exam, I've made a simple quiz app for me and my classmates that goes through questions that will likely be asked on said exam. The layout of the main question screen is displayed below.

[image]

As you can see, rather than using the toolbar to display a title ("quiz screen") I have used it to display the entire question, and question number. In addition, I've disabled the back button. Now for the question: is this layout, and use of the toolbar specifically, in concordance with the material design guidelines? I have looked through https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html, where one would expect to find such information, rather extensively, but have found no answer to this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the toolbar is used to provide hint of what the data in the current screen is about. It should not contain more than more two lines of text.(For two lines of text, use a [collapsing toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) and for a single line use the ordinary toolbar). Coming to your app, I'd suggest you put the question number in the toolbar i.e "Question 3" and the question should be an ordinary textview with about 24sp in text size. Moreover, remove the FAB from the screen and use a  [flat button](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html) instead. The FAB button must not be abused

Comment: Thanks a lot for the flat button suggestion, will definitely change that.

Comment: The problem I have with just making the question a plain textview is that it makes the app look extremely... linear and boring. I have tried it previously,  and even gave the layout that contained the question TextView my primary light color as background, but it didn't look amazing. Whereas right now, because the background of the toolbar is the primary app color, the question really jumps to the foreground.

If the guidelines say this is not how a toolbar should be used, however, I will comply :)

Comment: Maybe try some bold colors for the question and toolbar. Try to use amber with HEX color value of #FFC107 for the color of your toolbar and then add the question number as the text like I told you before "Question 3" but make it's textcolor #747474 and the typeface roboLight. The question's text color should also be #747474 but not in the toolbar. It's text should be a lot larger than the answers, maybe 32sp or 36sp. Lastly, make the text color for the answers #bebebe (this is a beautiful grey color).  [Read this] ( https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and references. As you can probably tell, im fairly new to android/material design. This will most definitely come in handy!

Comment: You are welcome!! If you need some UI design inspiration check out [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/)  you're find lots of designs there. All the best with your exams